# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am getting value from a `textBox` in a database table and showing it in a `gridView` but this 1 field is giving an error.

**Code and Exeception :**

[image]

Comment: You're trying to convert what is basically a string into an int - what's not clear about the error?   You need to post the code that is throwing the error - as text, not as a picture.

Comment: im not converting any thing its converting by its self

Comment: the value in the database is varchar in just trying to take a value from the textbox as text and adding it in a database but this exception is popping out

Comment: "im not converting any thing its converting by itself"  Um, no.  You may not intentionally be trying to convert, but an implicit conversion is being attempted for some reason.   That reason is in your code, and without your code we can't help you.

Comment: i have sent the code on your fb messanger can you plz take a look at it it would help me greatly

Comment: Please don't send unsolicited code.  Simply post the relevant section of your code where the error is occurring, and perhaps the table schema.  If you're not sure how to do that, take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get string value in int type variable. Use string instead.
Or post your code here

Comment: Your answer is merely a copy of the comment Tim has written on the question. Regardless of that, this is also not really an answer, but should rather be a comment as well.